# Why is it valid to call new again here?

Tags: javascript

In the following JavaScript code, new is used twice but it's not an error:

```
function Foo(i) {
        this.i = i;
}

Foo.specialConstructor = function() {
        return new Foo(1337);
};

foo = new Foo.specialConstructor();
console.log(foo.i);
```

However, following code causes `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`:

```
foo = new (new Foo(1337));
```

Why the second case causes an error while the first doesn't?

Comment: Try `new (Foo.specialConstructor())` to see the difference (to your `new (Foo.specialConstructor)()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is not an error because if a constructor returns a non-primitive value, it is returned instead of the object created. Therefore, simplified, following happens:

1. A new object is created
2. The new object's internal `__proto__` variable is set to `Foo.specialConstructor.prototype`
3. `Foo.specialConstructor` is executed using the created object as a this variable
4. Because `Foo.specialConstructor` returns a non-primitive value, it is returned by the new operator instead of the newly created object

The second case is an error because the new operator can only be used on functions.