# What is the purpose of using new operator in this example?

Tags: javascript

Why would you use the `new` operator in succession like in the example below.

```
var x = 0;
function foo() {
    x++;
    this.x = x;
    return foo;
}
var bar = new new foo;
console.log(bar.x); //undefined
```

**UPDATE**
Actually I didn't notice at first, but when you do:

```
var bar = new new foo; //you'll get `undefined` `undefined` returned
```

As opposed to:

```
var bar = new foo; //you'll get `undefined` returned
```

**UPDATE**
As Bergi correctly pointed out you'll only get one `undefined`..Sorry I must not have had enough coffee :)

Comment: I believe you can do that because your function returns a function so the new new is legal and works. Since the function returns itself and you want to instantiate a new instance of it instead of the previous one you can new the return. So you say give me a new foo and that returns foo so you new the return as well so its not a reference to the previous foo. And this is all possible since functions are really just objects anyway.

Comment: The real question is *why* would anyone do this?

Comment: @j08691: To demonstrate what happens when you return objects from constructors

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz: Where did you find this example? We could use some context, please.

Comment: "*you'll get `undefined` `undefined` returned*" - surely not, a function can only return a single value only.

Comment: @j08691 - I hear ya. But that's the point in my question in a way. To me it's confusing. But so were closures at one point. ;)

Comment: @Bergi This online Quiz http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=13

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz: It could just be in that quiz to mess with you and may not represent how you *should* code.

Comment: @Bergi Well I tried it chrome and those were the differences...I'll edit my update...

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz: Ah, I guessed that. Other result google brought up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27881368/1048572 https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2rc3nb/new_new_foo_is_not_a_syntax_error_is_this/ https://gist.github.com/MattSurabian/8867307

Comment: @Rocket—There seems to be a lot of that, especially in those 'JS-interview-questions' I see everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of using `new` operator in this example?

To baffle you. A lot.

> Why would you use the new operator in succession?

You would never, unless you would want to demonstrate that weird code can still work. Although it needs a higher-order function (which returns another function) instead of a normal constructor for that.

OK, let's make it less weird:

```
var x = new   new Function("this.foo = 'bar';") ();
//          ^ notice the invisible parenthesis ^
x.foo; // bar
```